# Prometheus : Proxy Component to Push matrices to PushGateway

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

[image]

In the system we are building, we need to monitor components(Kafka Connect,Spark..etc) runs in k8s cluster using Prometheus.
Since k8s cluster runs in a different network, Prometheus server cannot scrape these components directly.
For this, we are going to run a PushGateWay in our k8s cluster.

I come up with the following design :

1. Custom built "Push Proxy" component reads "kube-api-service" to get the list of pods for each component we want to monitor.(Also periodically checks pod health/check new pods..etc)
2. The "Push Proxy" periodically scraps Exporters in each pod. (Calling /metrics endpoint of each pod).
   Store these scraped matrices in a buffer.
3. "Push Proxy" periodically push the buffered matrices to the PushGateWay.
4. This PushGateWay is accessible from Prometheus. Prometheus scrapes matrices periodically from the PushGW.

Questions are:

1. is there any component like the "Push Proxy" we are planning on building?
2. Is this a valid design to handle this problem.

Comment: why don't you run prometheus as part of K8s cluster and it can push all the collected data to remote db like InfluxDb... where you can run grafana or Prometheus to monitor using the stored data ?

Comment: I am not sure to understand why you cannot poxyfy the scrapes from Prometheus (with nginx or miniproxy). Assuming you cannot bridge the networks, there is something similar to what you are talking about under development by RobustPerception: https://github.com/RobustPerception/PushProx. It may be what you are looking for. I have not tried it.

Comment: @AnshulJindal we have a MonitoringAsAService with provides Prometheus stack. We dont really want to maintain our own Prometheus